# Timer on STM32F

Tags: c, timer, embedded, stm32

I am trying to setup a general timer on a STM32F board usng HAL libraries. This is my impelementation so far:

```
static TIM_HandleTypeDef s_TimerInstance = { 
    .Instance = TIM2
};

void InitializeTimer() {   
    __TIM2_CLK_ENABLE();  
    s_TimerInstance.Init.Prescaler = 40000;  
    s_TimerInstance.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;  
    s_TimerInstance.Init.Period = 500;  
    s_TimerInstance.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;  
    s_TimerInstance.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;  
    HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&s_TimerInstance);  
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&s_TimerInstance); 
}
```

I am unable to access the members of `s_TimerInstance`.

> Field 'Init' could not be resolved

The header files included are as follows:

```
#include "stm32f0xx_hal.h"
#include "stm32f072xb.h"
#include "stm32f0xx_hal_tim.h"
```

The definition of TIM_HandleTypeDef is as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
  TIM_TypeDef              *Instance;     /*!< Register base address             */
  TIM_Base_InitTypeDef     Init;          /*!< TIM Time Base required parameters */
  HAL_TIM_ActiveChannel    Channel;       /*!< Active channel                    */
  DMA_HandleTypeDef        *hdma[7];      /*!< DMA Handlers array
                                             This array is accessed by a @ref TIM_DMA_Handle_index */
  HAL_LockTypeDef          Lock;          /*!< Locking object                    */
  __IO HAL_TIM_StateTypeDef   State;         /*!< TIM operation state               */
}TIM_HandleTypeDef;
```

Comment: What it says. There is no field "Init" in the struct or you forgot to include the header file with the struct declaration.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Probably some library path that's screwed up then. Let me guess, you are using Eclipse...

Comment: @Lundin yes, I am

Comment: That's perfectly normal then. The whole purpose of Eclipse is to obscure all library paths and give strange linker errors. Developers often think that the solution is to manually fiddle around with Eclipse library paths for a couple of weeks. But in fact it is far cheaper to uninstall Eclipse and buy a useful tool instead.

Comment: This does not solve the problem because I have to use Eclipse

Comment: The problem is Eclipse itself. Trust me. I could tell that you used it just by recognizing the nature of the so-called bug, caused by the IDE itself. I have used it far too much and too often. The sooner you realize what a PoS it is, the sooner you can get back to doing actual programming.

Comment: This is probably just an Eclipse error and not an actual build error. You can switch these off. Working on a daily basis with IAR, KEIL, CCS, DS-5 and numerous other Eclipse based environments I have actually come to quite like Eclipse. At least it is roughly the same when switching between different tools and works pretty well once you understand it.

Comment: @RealtimeRik Then surely you should be able to answer this question in a few minutes. Because Eclipse doesn't create new, unique linker bugs for you to solve several times per week, at all. Right? It's so good, except for the fact that it never works.

Comment: @Lundin I never said that it was so good. But it does work fairly well and apart from a few manufacturers most development environments seem to be going the Eclipse way. I will admit I used to hate it, but being forced to use it, as that what my customers want, it has grown on me.

Comment: Well alternative for eclipse could be simple Makefile, own text editor(vim,emacs) , gdb tools , openOCD debugger and some scripting. For very start you can find makefile based solutions at Github. Once you'll get some experience with makefiles and gdb and scripting, you'll find that it is much better than Eclipse. In this way you can control much more and your background will be much more steady. It's free like eclipse, maybe it is little harder approach, but it is worth.

Comment: @David.O thanks a lot :)